# Image View surround with Text

Tags: android, textview, imageview

[image]

how make some thing like this , Image View surround with Text
i mean , image appear inside Text

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: try to make text view surround img , like this pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [TextViewOverflowing](https://github.com/JustinAngel/TextViewOverflowing)
[image]

Comment: @user3623824 You're welcome. Mark my answer is right when you have time. Thanks :)